# Conditional Select using a file

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a file with a list of identifying attributes, one on each line. I'd like to use these as part of a conditional select statement to psql. The same query I'm thinking of is:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where mykey IN ('contents of file');
```

I'd like to point the IN construct to the file (which is being generated from another database and script.) Every entry in the file will be in `mytable`

Is there a way to do this in psql from the command line? My intention is to run this as part of a bash script on our servers.

Comment: Either import the file into a temporary table (using `\copy` or `copy`) or use a [foreign data wrapper](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fdw#File_Wrappers) that can access the file directly (but that requires the file to be present on the DB server)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's more or less what I ended up doing. Add your comment as an answer and I'll approve it?